# How to set UL parameter when using jquery autocomplete _renderItem

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

So this is my code... the "UL" is the first parameter of the function, how do I specify a selector to pass in?

```
$(".placeSearch").autocomplete({
        source: '/placeSearch/',
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $("[name='placeId']").val(ui.item.id);
            $(".displayAddress").html(ui.item.id);
        },
        autoFocus: true
    }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                                                return $( "<li></li>" )
                                                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                                                    .append( "<a>" + item.id + ' ' + item.label + "</a>")
                                                    .appendTo(ul) 
                                                };
```

Comment: What do you mean by *assigning a selector* to it?

Comment: I've got 2 UL's and it's pointing at the wrong one.. how do I get it to point to the right one? short of doing this...                                                                                                          **.appendTo(ul) -> .appendTo("#results")**